# Duplicate a liberty server, application won't start

Tags: java-8, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have installed on my laptop a Liberty server, just unzipped, launched `server create <name>` and copied some files from the remote server test environment and put a `.war` with a local configuration.
Run the server through command line and the application is working.

Now I tried to do the same on a colleague laptop, but the application seems that is started, but when I call a rest endpoint I have no response, just an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` from browser.
I tried to copy my exact folder on his laptop, same problem. I tried to copy my server folder on another folder in my laptop, same problem. I tried with different version of the server, but nothing change. I tried to copy the server from test environment on my laptop and using my .war, no way. The `.war` is always the same, the one that's working on my first attempt, I checked to not have hard-coded path.

The log:

```
...

com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/idsWS/
com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/idsWS
com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
io.jaegertracing.Configuration                               I Initialized tracer=JaegerTracer(version=Java-0.34.0, serviceName=ws-ids, reporter=RemoteReporter(sender=UdpSender(), closeEnqueueTimeout=1000), sampler=RemoteControlledSampler(maxOperations=2000, manager=HttpSamplingManager(hostPort=localhost:5778), sampler=ProbabilisticSampler(tags={sampler.type=probabilistic, sampler.param=0.001})), tags={hostname=CTXW10VDDN-006, jaeger.version=Java-0.34.0, ip=26.0.226.195}, zipkinSharedRpcSpan=false, expandExceptionLogs=false, useTraceId128Bit=false)
m.ibm.ws.microprofile.opentracing.jaeger.JaegerTracerFactory I CWMOT1001I: A JaegerTracer instance was created for the ws-ids application.  Tracing information is sent to localhost:6831.
com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application ws-ids started in 39.529 seconds.

<--------------------------------------------> 

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension                            W SRVE0190E: File not found: /openapi/ui/
.jaxrs20.cdi.component.JaxRsFactoryImplicitBeanCDICustomizer W CWWKW1002W: The CDI scope of JAXRS Provider FakeRestFilter is javax.enterprise.context.Dependent. Liberty gets the provider instance from CDI.
.jaxrs20.cdi.component.JaxRsFactoryImplicitBeanCDICustomizer W CWWKW1002W: The CDI scope of JAXRS Provider PortaleCookieFilterRest is javax.enterprise.context.Dependent. Liberty gets the provider instance from CDI.
.jaxrs20.cdi.component.JaxRsFactoryImplicitBeanCDICustomizer W CWWKW1002W: The CDI scope of JAXRS Provider BusinessExceptionMapper is javax.enterprise.context.Dependent. Liberty gets the provider instance from CDI.
.jaxrs20.cdi.component.JaxRsFactoryImplicitBeanCDICustomizer W CWWKW1002W: The CDI scope of JAXRS Provider GenericExceptionMapper is javax.enterprise.context.Dependent. Liberty gets the provider instance from CDI.
.jaxrs20.cdi.component.JaxRsFactoryImplicitBeanCDICustomizer W CWWKW1002W: The CDI scope of JAXRS Provider UnknownUrlExceptionMapper is javax.enterprise.context.Dependent. Liberty gets the provider instance from CDI.
.jaxrs20.cdi.component.JaxRsFactoryImplicitBeanCDICustomizer W CWWKW1002W: The CDI scope of JAXRS Provider ValidationExceptionMapper is javax.enterprise.context.Dependent. Liberty gets the provider instance from CDI.
.apache.cxf.cxf.core.3.2:1.0.71.cl221220221107-1900(id=116)] I Setting the server's publish address to be /api/
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [ws-ids] [/idsWS] [it.sogei.dichiarazioneids.ws.server.JAXRSActivator]: Initialization successful.
eclipselink                                                  I CWWJP9990I: [eclipselink] EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.11.v20220804-52dea2a3c0
com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.DatabaseHelper                     I DSRA8203I: Database product name : Oracle
com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.DatabaseHelper                     I DSRA8204I: Database product version : Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.DatabaseHelper                     I DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name  : Oracle JDBC driver
com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.DatabaseHelper                     I DSRA8206I: JDBC driver version  : 12.2.0.1.0
```

Before the line the logs are the same, below the line only the working application write the logs after that an endpoint is called. If I call the same api url on my colleague laptop, too if as written in the logs above the application ws-ids seems started, no others logs are written.

I understand that I'm not giving much information, but the `server.xml`, `server.env` and the `.war` and all the other configuration file are really the same.
It seems like the server is starting my application, without loading it to the server. Any idea? Which information could I add?

Comment: When you're testing your colleagues server, are you running the browser locally or from your desktop?   What url are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you are both using same Liberty server version? The easiest way, if you want the copy, would be to package the server and then copy the archive with server and app. Then you just unpack it all on college laptop. Check the `server package` command - https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/command/server-package.html

Comment: @FRowe I'm running the browser locally on my colleague laptop. To Gas: The liberty version are the same, I zipped the entire directory and unzipped on the same path on another laptop. Hovewer I'll give a try to the package command.

Comment: Ok the problem was on the server. When a class of my application was loaded on the server startup, sometimes my server go up and worked, but after few times that I restarted the server (too if used the --clean option) my server didn't work too. Strangely my colleagues server never ever worked. But fixing the class problem, fixed the problem across all servers. Maybe I should delete this question...